# Set API TOKEN for new users Lumen/Laravel

Tags: laravel, api, lumen

I am getting started with lumen.

this is my `web.php` file

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'api'], function () use ($router) {

    $router->post('user', ['uses' => 'UserController@createUser']);

});
```

and this is my `UserController.php`

```
public function createUser(Request $request){

    $this->validate($request, [
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required|min:3'
    ]);
    $user = [
        'username' => $request->username,
        'password' => app('hash')->make($request->password),
        'email' => $request->email,
        'api_token' => 'asdfasd' //want should I put here
    ];

    $user = User::create($user);


    return response()->json($user, 201);
}
```

How do I create a new api token for that a new user who is registering?

Comment: see https://seegatesite.com/restful-api-tutorial-with-lumen-laravel-5-5-for-beginners/